# Getting full path in C++ adjacency list Dijkstra

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, dijkstra, adjacency-list

I want to get full path in adjacency list Dijkstra algorithm using C++ queue. Graph edges are oriented.

Dijkstra algorithm works fine and I understand why. However getting full path is a bit more complicated to me, this usually described much less than Dijkstra algorithm itself. I tried to reused a few solutions ([this, for example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-paths-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/)) I've found for square matrix, but it didn't worked for my adjacency list implementation.

Part I'm stucked with:

```
int dijkstra(int start, int finish)
{
    //some code
    parent.resize(vertex_count(), -1);
    while (!q.empty()) {
        //some code
        for (auto edge : link[current]) {
            if (dist[current] + edge.weight < dist[edge.to]) {
                dist[edge.to] = dist[current] + edge.weight;
                parent[edge.to] = start;
                q.push(QueueVertex(edge.to,dist[edge.to]));
            }
        }
    }
    path(parent);
    return dist[finish];
}
void path(vector<int> parent) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < parent.size(); i++) {
        if (parent[i] != -1)
            cout << i << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Full code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <queue>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>
    #include <climits>
    #define INF INT_MAX
    using namespace std;
    
    struct Edge
    {
        int to;
        int weight;
        Edge() {}
        Edge(int to, int weight) : to(to), weight(weight) {}
        void read() {
            cin >> to >> weight;
        }
    };
    struct QueueVertex
    {
        int number;
        int dist;
        QueueVertex(int number, int dist) : number(number), dist(dist) {}
    };
    bool operator<(const QueueVertex& v1, const QueueVertex& v2) {
        return v1.dist > v2.dist;
    }
    class Graph
    {
        vector<vector<Edge>> link;
        vector <int> dist;
        vector<int> parent = {};
    public:
        Graph(int vertex_count) :
            link(vertex_count) {}
        void add_edge_u(int from, int to, int weight) { //unoriented
            link[from].push_back(Edge(to, weight));
            link[to].push_back(Edge(from, weight));
        }
        void add_edge_o(int from, int to, int weight) { //oriented
            link[from].push_back(Edge(to, weight));
        }
        int vertex_count() const {
            return link.size();
        }
        int dijkstra(int start, int finish)
        {
            dist.resize(vertex_count(), INF);
            dist[start] = 0;
            parent.resize(vertex_count(), -1);
            priority_queue <QueueVertex> q;
            q.push(QueueVertex(start, 0));
            while (!q.empty()) {
                int current = q.top().number;
                int current_dist = q.top().dist;
                q.pop();
                if (current_dist > dist[current]) {
                    continue;
                }
                for (auto edge : link[current]) {
                    if (dist[current] + edge.weight < dist[edge.to]) {
                        dist[edge.to] = dist[current] + edge.weight;
                        parent[edge.to] = start;
                        q.push(QueueVertex(edge.to,dist[edge.to]));
                    }
                }
            }
            path(parent);
            return dist[finish];
        }
        void path(vector<int> parent) {
            for (auto i = 0; i < parent.size(); i++) {
                if (parent[i] != -1)
                    cout << i << ' ';
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    };
    
    
    int main()
    {
{
    int n = 3, m = 3, start = 1, finish = 0;
    Graph gr(n);
    gr.add_edge_o(0, 1, 1);
    gr.add_edge_o(1, 2, 2);
    gr.add_edge_o(2, 3, 5);
    gr.add_edge_o(3, 0, 4);
    int dist = gr.dijkstra(start, finish);
    cout << dist << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Desirable output (program getting 11 just fine, but not 1 2 3 0 part):

```
1 2 3 0
11
```

Thank you.

Comment: [What is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: 1) `Edge() {}` -- You forgot to initialize all of your member variables.  2) `cin >> n >> m;` -- `int start, finish; cin >> start >> finish;` -- Please put the test data directly into the variables instead of using `cin`.  If someone were to take your program, compile and run it, they have to manually enter the test data every time they run the program.  To alleviate this, and to also help you to debug the program, the variables, arrays, etc. should be populated with the test data directly.  Expected is a program that declares a Graph, adds edges to it directly, and outputs the results.

Comment: [This is what is to be expected for the main function](https://godbolt.org/z/Mqasxnx8s).  No `cin` calls, but simply a declaration of a graph, adding edges, and calling the `dijkstra` function.

Comment: @Paul
Have put the data directly instead of cin to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `path` function makes no sense. You should be using the `parent` array to walk backwards from the goal state to the start. As written, this function simply outputs all the parents. Consider something like this:

```
deque<int> path;
while(finish != -1)
{
    path.push_front(finish);
    finish = (finish == start) ? -1 : parent[finish];
}

for (int node : path) cout << (node + 1) << ' ';
cout << endl;
```

Note that the above uses a `std::deque` for convenience, since the path is built in reverse. But you can use a `std::vector` if you wish, and either reverse it or walk over it with a reverse_iterator.

Now that the path is being built correctly, you'll quickly see another problem, which is that your `parent` table is not being built correctly. You're doing this:

```
parent[edge.to] = start;    //<-- incorrect
```

That looks like a copy/paste error, because you don't want every node's parent to point back at the start. The parent of the edge being examined is stored in `current`:

```
parent[edge.to] = current;  //<-- correct
```